Strategies for Visualizing Large Graph in Neo4j Databases
I am working on a project that involves a Neo4j graph database with thousands of nodes and relationships. However, I'm facing difficulties in visualizing the graph due to the high number of nodes and relationships. The default Neo4j Browser doesn't provide a structured visual, and the graph keeps moving, becoming messy and hard to comprehend.
I have been using the Data Explorer for Neo4j to keep the visual organized, but I'm still looking for better strategies or tools to visualize the graph more cleanly and in a structured manner. What strategies can I employ to group nodes together based on shared characteristics or properties, allowing me to focus on relevant subsets of the graph? Maybe grouping nodes together, displaying only relevant subsets at a time, and incorporating an expand or collapse feature.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I tried using neo4j bloom but that doesn't give me best visual as visualizing thousands of nodes and relationships.
